# Can a user undelete an answer that was deleted by a moderator?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, moderators, undelete, trolling

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2771087/selecting-countries-with-largest-populations-in-sql/2771464#2771464), posted by a troll, had previously been deleted by a moderator (I believe it was Bill the Lizard). Recently it got undeleted, at about the same time the user made a comment under it. This leads me to believe that the user himself undeleted it. Is this possible? If so, what's the value of moderators deleting answers?

In case it gets deleted again, the answer told someone who asked about making an sql query to use the `DROP TABLE` command. All of this user's posts have been trolls, most of which have been deleted by now.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out.  I wasn't aware that users could undelete their own posts either.

Comment: @bill, only answers, not questions

Comment: @Downvoter: That explains why every question I've ever deleted hasn't come right back to life. :)  For some reason it never occurred to me that answers aren't voted on for deletion in the same way, and so need to be locked.

Comment: @Bill: My guess is that both work the same way, but is impossible for a user to get to his closed questions, while being easy to see his deleted answers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Edit**: This has been changed, see - [Users should not be able to undelete answers deleted by a moderator](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77380/users-should-not-be-able-to-undelete-answers-deleted-by-a-moderator)

---

If the answer is not locked, it can be <s>undeleted by owner</s>. (not any more)

<sub>There is some flags on that answer, so probably that will be deleted and locked by community soon.</sub>

Comment: Thank you.  I've deleted and *locked* it this time.

Comment: But this is wrong, My answer was deleted by @Kev and I fixed my answer but I am not allowed to undelete it still? CC: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4041468/231917

Comment: I agree with @zengr. My answer got deleted on [add-user-defined-fields-in-the-fix-dictionary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13402144/add-user-defined-fields-in-the-fix-dictionary) but I edited it, and corrected it. Shouldn't I be able to vote at least for undelete? Since I can't, I posted a new Answer. Or, at least a warning before the deletion would be nice, so that users can edit their answer and prevent it from being deleted.

Answer (score 3):

[This has been implemented.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77107/lock-posts-by-default-when-deleted-by-a-moderator/86481#86481)

Answer (score 2):

It most likely was deleted and undeleted by himself.

Flag as spam and/or for moderation attention. If a few flags are gathered on a single post, the user get a rep penalty and the post itself is deleted and locked.

I hid the content to avoid copypaste script kiddies dropping tables too easely.

Comment: It was definitely deleted by a moderator - I saw it before it was undeleted (I have 10k rep).

Comment: @interjay: then he must have forgot to lock it. Now we could just wait to gather the 6 votes to delete and lock that answer. Check its progress at http://stackoverflow.com/tools/flagged