# Do the posts deleted by an ex-mod become undeletable?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, deleted-answers, moderators, moderator-abilities

As we know, 10k+ users can see deleted posts and vote for their undeletion. And, anybody can see his own deleted posts, and over some reputation (s)he also have a vote to un-delete it.

Except posts deleted by a diamond moderator. They can be undeleted only by a mod:

[image]

I have a purely theoretical question from pure curiosity.

What happens, if the deleting mod is later de-modded? Will the posts (s)he deleted become undeletable again?

*P.s. the possible dupe is about the other direction (essentially: do the posts deleted by mod before he got the diamond is made un-undeletable retroactively). Although probably both depend on the same - missing or existing - feature of the SE software,*

1. It is clear only from a programmer viewpoint.
2. We don't know the internals of the SE software, maybe they are handled differently.
3. I think, this direction is much more important/interesting, because it could make posts public again, which shouldn't be ever publicized.

On these reasons, I don't think the other question would be an answer.

Next to these: The answers there contain only opinions, which are agreeable probably for everybody, but don't contain real information about this possibility.

Comment: (As always, improvements are welcomed, especially the grammar/spelling ones.)

Comment: All you need to do is find a mod alumnus (ex mod) and look at their activity, find a post they deleted when they were still a mod, and examine whether you can undelete it.  Mods can always undelete posts regardless of who deleted them, so there's no such thing as an undeletable post.

Comment: My expectation is that the delete is flagged as a special moderator delete so it doesn't matter who did it and whether they were currently a mod.

Comment: @AdamDavis Not having a 10k+ account, I can do this only with my own posts deleted by an ex-mod, and it is practically impossible to find them.

Comment: @AdamDavis I agree that it would be logical, but it can be also viewed as an unneeded complexity in the system. It depends on that the writers of the specification, or the implementing programmers were aware of this possibility, and they decided it deserves its price. If not, it can mean also a problematic point in the SE software (mod deletions can have other reasons as well, for example copyright problems, and in this case their un-deletion should be obviously impossible).

Comment: Hmm.  Well, my method won't be easy anyway since delete votes are not visible to other users.  I've been looking through Will's history but can't find a quick and easy check.

Comment: @AdamDavis I think it is also possible, that in the case of the (rare) de-moddings, the CMs post-fix this problem by hand (or, with a tool).

Comment: @AdamDavis I suspect, you have only a few deleted posts, but having a 10k+ or 3 different sites, you can search for them. Between them, maybe you can find an ex-mod between the deleters...

Comment: Well, for them to figure out if a vote is "binding" they'd have to run an *additional* query on the DB.  It may be they can optimize it into a query that's already being run, but it makes more sense to have a single column with the question status represented as a number, and have two different numbers for "closed by community" and "closed by moderator".  Each one would have different actions available, which is already the case depending on the post status.  I don't think they'd want all moderator actions undone when a mod retires, so it would be strange to have it set up that way.

Comment: I recall a question about this saying that undeletion was not possible even after the moderator gave back the diamond. I'm having trouble finding it, though. There [are cases where leaving the post marked as mod-deleted is definitely a good idea](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48929/can-a-user-undelete-an-answer-that-was-deleted-by-a-moderator).

Comment: Nope, I was wrong: the [current status of the deleting account is what's checked](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294118/). ([Also](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269513/).)

Comment: Here's an example, but the post is from 2010 and the system as changed since then.  It was closed and deleted by then mods, and now regular people: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1081293/books-on-opengl-es-targeted-towards-the-iphone/

Comment: @JoshCaswell That's surprising.  So all previous activities by a user become binding during their term, then unbinding once they retire?

Comment: @AdamDavis Unfortunately, to me it gives 404. Can you explain, what is there?

Comment: @AdamDavis As I know, for example in the case of the VtC/VtR votes, the bindingness of the mods only mean that his(her) decision happens on the spot, independent from the other votes. But, the questions closed/reopened by them, can be reopened/closed again by the community (or by another mod, or by a golden tag badge owner).

Comment: Apparently yes, @AdamDavis; I find it odd too, which is probably why I misremembered it.

Comment: The question example I posted above looks like this to me: http://i.stack.imgur.com/5OjeX.png  Note that at the two times binding action was taken Bill the Lizard and Will were mods, but neither are now and I am able to vote to reopen or undelete, though I'm not a mod.

Comment: In the "suspected dupe", Robert Cartaino explained how it _should_ be done on his opinion (what I agree), but probably even he didn't know at the time, how it is actually being done.

Comment: I thought I felt someone internet stalking me, @AdamDavis!

Comment: @Won't Well they don't make it easy these days.  I had to cut'n'paste the `?tab=activity` part of the URL since they don't provide a nice link on everyone else's profile!  BTW, I'm totally not peeking through your blinds right now, but you might want to check your fly.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's [a question where this is demonstrated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1081293/books-on-opengl-es-targeted-towards-the-iphone/).  It was closed by a mod, then years later deleted by a mod.  Neither are mods now, but I'm able to cast reopen and undelete votes.

[image: Bill the Lizard cast a binding close vote, Will a binding delete vote, neither are mods now, so options to reopen and undelete are shown to me, even though I'm not a mod]

---

Per these questions:

- [Is moderator retirement supposed to affect possibility of undeletion?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294118/is-moderator-retirement-supposed-to-affect-possibility-of-undeletion)
- [Can't undelete a closed question because a person who deleted it became a moderator](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269513/cant-undelete-a-closed-question-because-a-person-who-deleted-it-became-a-modera)
- [Deletion votes from users who later became moderators shouldn't prevent community undeletion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174860/deletion-votes-from-users-who-later-became-moderators-shouldnt-prevent-communit)

It's obvious that this is how the system works - the bindingness of votes is determined when the question or answer is displayed, and not some intrinsic vote type.

Once someone becomes a moderator *all* their previous votes are treated as moderator votes, and once someone retires *all* their previous votes are treated as regular votes.

This won't reopen or undelete questions, though, even though they normally require 5 votes to close, for instance.  The status of the question remains the same, but the actions available to other users in reversing moderator decisions is changed.

---

None of the questions posed above provide insight as to why Stack Exchange has chosen this method.  It's possible it's simply due to the way moderator powers were an extension of reputation powers, which are checked each time, and since a reduction in reputation reduces powers then it would follow that the same happens to moderators.

However I don't think that's necessarily a good design - it may simply be an accident of development inertia.

A decision made by a moderator isn't meant to represent that moderator - it's meant to represent the moderator team, and shouldn't necessarily go away just because the person moved on.

Alas, no one from Stack Exchange has chimed in so we don't really know if this is by design, or simply how it was implemented at the time and never revisited once moderators started resigning.

Comment: Yes, you can vote to undelete. I did and the counter is on 1 now. Please stop testing now or this question will get undeleted :)

Comment: @PatrickHofman Ha!

Comment: Now I just need to wait until Animuson retires so I can unlock [my best post ever.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99062/dont-close-questions-where-the-user-has-requested-that-it-not-be-closed)

Comment: @AdamDavis So you can lose more reputation? =)

Comment: No, @Nathaniel. You should see the irony. It would have my vote :)

Comment: @Nathaniel Oh that's just one of many benefits!  For instance, it's still the lowest voted but still open question on meta.  The only reluctance I have, though, is that it has exactly 42 upvotes, which is a nice round number.

Comment: @PatrickHofman True, it *is* pretty funny. I'm a big fan of the migrate to Yahoo! answers idea.

Comment: Looks like it won't work anyway.  My other popular locked post was locked by a mod who is no longer a mod, but I can't unlock it: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41976/question-title-that-doesnt-describe-the-problem

Comment: @AdamDavis I think locks are independent entities from the locking user, thus the locked-ness of a question is checked if you want to vote for it. While, the question is, that in the case of the undelete votes, what is checked: 1) Is somebody a mod between the delete voters? 2) Was somebody a mod between the closers *at time of the closure?*

Comment: @peterh Yes, Locks are a mod only power, so even ence they lose their mod privileges lock and unlock don't become available to others they wouldn't normally be available to. Guess the 42 upvotes is going to have to stay!